# How can I reset the <div> class name?

Tags: css, velocity

I have velocity template code where I am generating class name on the basis of for loop. Is it possible to reset the div name when one of the for loop iteration does not match the criteria.
Code I have written:

```
  #set ($size = $confs.size())
  #set ( $prev = "mycontent" )
  #foreach($i in [0..$size])

  #if($i < $size)
            </br>
    <table>
        <tbody>

          <tr class="impact-soy" data-key="$confs.get($i).impact">

              <div class=impact-$i>
                  <span>$confs.get($i).impact</span>
              </div>



                  #if($prev != $confs.get($i).actor)
                  <div class=actors-$i style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                      <span>$confs.get($i).actor</span>
                      #set ($prev = $confs.get($i).actor)
                  </div>

                  #else

                  #end

              <script>

                  $(document).ready(function() {


                      $('div.impact-$i').connections({ from: 'div.actors-$i' }).length;
                      var connections = $('connection, inner');
                      setInterval(function() { connections.connections('update') }, 100);
                  });
              </script>

          </tr>

        </tbody>
        </table>
        #end
        #end
```

else block should reset the class name to previous if block executed class name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
 #set ($prev = "Test")
   <div class=actors-$i>

        #if($prev != $Confs.get($i).actor)
                 <span>$Confs.get($i).actor</span>
                 #set ($prev = $Confs.get($i).actor)
        #else
            //do nothing and reset the div class to previous true //valid condition
            $('.actor-'+$i).addClass('true'+$i);
            $('.true'+$i).removeClass('actor-'+$i).addClass('actor-'+($i-1));

        #end
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Bhavin :I added <script>
 $('.actor-'+$i).addClass('true').removeClass('actor-'+$i);
               </script>. Still I get the same result and after inspecting in browser I can see that class name is not resetting.

Comment: No the class name changes to true1

Comment: so what do you mean by reset name? what exactly you want

Comment: I want to reset it to "if" part div class name basically where the condition holds true.

Comment: so do you want to reset class with which/what?

Comment: so let's say when the if condition holds true the class name was actors-0 and in next iteration if it is invalid (let's say actors-1) so I want it to reset to actors-0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83993/discussion-between-bhavin-solanki-and-user2900150).